# Unable to generate report using html screen shot in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, testing, protractor

I'm trying to generate reports using html screen shot in protractor, have followed all the steps, but am getting an error. Please help.

My conf.js

```
// An example configuration file.
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');
var reporter=new HtmlReporter({
    baseDirectory: './protractor-result', // a location to store screen shots.
    docTitle: 'Protractor Demo Reporter',
    docName:    'protractor-demo-tests-report.html'
});
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directly when
  // protractor is called.
  specs: ['example_spec.js'],

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }

  onPrepare: function() {
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter),
    };
};
```

Error I'm getting: Unexpected Error.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at ConfigParser.addFileConfig (C:\Users\jeevan.s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\configParser.js:183:20)
    at Object.init (C:\Users\jeevan.s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\launcher.js:35:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jeevan.s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\cli.js:129:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

Comment: Hope you installed the html-screenshot-reporter before using it. 
npm install protractor-html-screenshot-reporter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have syntax errors:

- missing `,` before the `onPrepare()`:
- replace `,` with `;` after the `addReporter()` call
- remove the `;` after `onPrepare()`

Fixed version:

```
// An example configuration file.
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');
var reporter=new HtmlReporter({
    baseDirectory: './protractor-result', // a location to store screen shots.
    docTitle: 'Protractor Demo Reporter',
    docName:    'protractor-demo-tests-report.html'
});
exports.config = {
    directConnect: true,

    // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },

    // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directly when
    // protractor is called.
    specs: ['example_spec.js'],

    // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    },

    onPrepare: function() {
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This particular site assisted me alot
https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter

This fix also added a savePath.

What I did was Added the following var to the Conf.js file and updated the Framework: to 'Jasmine2' and the following, this is my complete conf.js file:

```
// conf.js
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');

exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['*.js'],
    onPrepare: function() {
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
            new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
                savePath: 'target/screenshots'
            })
        );
    }
}
```